# PrintService in java not doing anything

Tags: java, jvm, printers

i trying to print some doc that i have with java application.
but when i choosing the printer its adding the file to the printer queue but nothing happend after the queue cleared.

this is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.JobName;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, attrs);
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        
        PrintService selection = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, services, service, null, attrs); 
        if(selection != null)
        {
            String fileName = "C:\\Temp\\test.docx";
            File f = new File(fileName);
            
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            
            DocPrintJob job = selection.createPrintJob();

            SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
            
            PrintRequestAttributeSet jAttrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            jAttrs.add(new JobName(fileName, null));
            
            job.print(doc, jAttrs);

            if(is != null)
                is.close();
            
        }
    }

}
```

this is capture of the printer queue when i choosing printer in the dialog and click "print":
[image]

and in my printer there is no information about printing job...

when i print this file from the pc and not from the app its working perfect.
and when i using this java code:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(f);
```

its printing perfect.
but its not what i want, i want that the user will choose printer in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an old program and a new printer (Hp 477dw). The solution is to install a PCL6 universal driver.